# My jquery.min.js can't be cached on AWS S3/CloudFront

Tags: jquery, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I set cache-control to one year (in ms) and content-type is application/x-javascript. I don't know why it won't get cached. I am using my cdn (with cname set, via CloudFront and using the best edge locations). And it keeps returning 304 in status code, instead of 200 (which means for cached). I don't know what to do, it's not loading a whole file, it seems like it's semi-cached, and it's loading 336B in 100ms+ which is not acceptable. What to do? I'm testing this on my localhost and production website with nginx and php-fpm.

Comment: Can you add command line you use to query for resource (curl?) and its verbose output? I think returning of 200 vs 304 really depends on the headers that are sent

Comment: I solved it by adding cache-control public, max-age=1year and making expire header for 5 years.